# Why was my question about Raspberry Pi GPIO marked as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

My question here was marked as off-topic:
*[Using incrontab to read GPIO's](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19712/using-incrontab-to-read-gpios)*

Even though it has to do with Raspberry Pi GPIO and connected hardware that is defined as on-topic in the help section.

Yes, I know that I don't specifically mention Raspberry Pi in the question, but I feel that it's implicative that I ask a question about Raspberry Pi hardware/software by placing it on a Raspberry Pi site.

Comment: I'll poke @Goldilocks to come and answer this for you, since he was the one that closed the question. :)

Answer (score 5):

I closed the question because it really doesn't have anything to do with the Raspberry Pi, but I can see now how this might not be obvious. I had hoped my comment would clarify this.<sup>1</sup> Let me explain:

> it has to do with Raspberry Pi GPIO and connected hardware

Tangentially, but you rule out any issue with this when you point out that

> when I "cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio24/value" I get a "1" when theres no motion, and "0" when theres motion. And when I do "cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio25/value", I get a "1" when the cover on the motion detector is closed, and "0" when the cover is open.

So there is no question of a GPIO problem; everything is working exactly the way it is supposed to. The crux of the issue is you are trying to use inotify to monitor a sysfs "file". I've reopened the question and turned my comment into [an answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/26377/5538) going into more detail.

Considering the fact that this is probably a more significant issue on the Raspberry Pi than for Linux users generally, I made the wrong call with this and apologize. My thought at the time, since I knew there is no solution to this problem, was to explain briefly why what you were trying to do *can't* work in a comment and just close the question, rather than migrating it to [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

---

<sup>1. To which I now notice you replied shortly after, but since the comment was not directed at me, I was not aware of this. If you want the attention of someone on a Stack Exchange site, make sure you include, e.g.,`@goldilocks` in the comment. This will only work if that person has already posted a comment in the same thread. The interface provides auto-completion for this after you type @ and the first few characters.</sup>